# How can I specify which database connection Laravel uses for the migration table?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-4

I'm working on an app with multiple database connections. It seems when I run **php artisan migrate:install** it always creates the migrations table using my default connection in app/config/database.php, which is not ideal.

Is there a way to specify a different connection for the migrations table itself?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

### Update

For anyone with a similar question, I found a better answer.

Looks like you can't specify the connection from a config file or anything, but you can when you run migrate from the command line...

```
php artisan migrate:install --database=NAME_OF_CONNECTION
```

**There is one caveat:** anytime you run an actual migration you must also specify the database connection with `--database` again or it will re-create the migrations table using the default connection.

Answer (score 4):

Edit: Looks like you want to change where the migrations table is stored. This I believe always uses the default. You can however specify where a table is supposed to be created as below:

You can specify a connection like so:

```
Schema::connection('foo')->create('users', function($table)
{
    $table->increments('id');
});
```

From http://laravel.com/docs/schema

Comment: Yeah I figured out how to specify which connection to use when writing a migration, but my architecture has an entire database dedicated to admin type stuff like this so I wanted to put the migrations table there instead. :/

Comment: You'd have to submit a feature request then to be able to change where the migrations table is stored.

Answer (score 1):

In Laravel 5.5 this worked for me:

```
php artisan migrate --database=sqlite_testing
```